# ViewController does not have a member named tableview error

Tags: uitableview, swift

I want to pass indexPath.row of the clicked row to another controller, so I used the next code, but it prints the error, that view controller does not have a member named tableview.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "body"{
        var secondViewController : SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() //get index of data for selected row

        secondViewController.data = indexPath.row // get data by index and pass it to second view controller

    }
}
```

Can I fix this error?

Comment: it's `tableView` not `tableview` .

Comment: @Carrl oh, thank you! I did not detect it =/ but now I have the next error: `Cannot invoke 'indexPathForSelectedRow' with no arguments`

Comment: @DharmeshKheni `Could not find member 'row'`

Comment: I have tried your code, it works fine for me, I have no idea what happens to you.

Comment: Did you try unwrapping the indexPath value ?

Comment: @Carrl did it println row index?

Comment: @DejanSkledar indexPath!.row I use

Comment: indexPath is not optional inside the brackets

Comment: @DharmeshKheni but it doesn't access me to set to the label.text the indexPath!.row value, because of it's Int

Comment: `indexPath.row.description` did you try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tableView doesn't exists there. and it is not a tableView function.

You have to create an strong outlet for the `tableView` like this:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

and don't forget to connect this to your `tableView`

and delete override from the methods TableView.

**EDIT:**

For your another problem you can follow Kirsteins as he suggested:

`tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` method returns an optional `NSIndexPath`. You have to unwrap it. However the best approach would be handle the situation with safely unwrap using `if let` where there is no selected row and `indexPath` is `nil`. Something like:

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
    secondViewController.tempString = indexPath.row.description
} else {
    // handle the situation where the is no selected row
}
```

and declare a variable into your SecondViewController which will hold this value.

Check [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForSelectedRow) for more Info.

Comment: oh, yes! It works, but the last thing: when I use `secondViewController.rowIndex.text = "\(indexPath!.row)"` it crashes with the next error:  `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: my secondController doesn't have .data, so I changed it to `secondViewController.rowIndex.text = "\(indexPath!.row)"`. And I need just pass my row indexPath.row to the second controller. I do not need `else` here =/ just one way. How can I do it and why this error appears? `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: debug you code and check weather you are getting your values or not.

Comment: it doesn't show me the list of news in tableView now =/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74905/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-orkhan-alizade).

Comment: Never assign values of UI from another ViewController.